# Cross-Origin Request Blocked graphhopper routing service

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, graphhopper

I got this error when I tried to call graphhopper routing service from my html page with jQuery ajax. It work when I run html page in browser but not work when I hosted the page on web server.

```
$.ajax({
    timeout: 5000,
    url: https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route?locale=en&.... points and key ,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true
})
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route?locale=en&point

Comment: What error..? where is the code ? please elaborate your question to find a solution.

Comment: Edited my question added my code.

Comment: Would you please try if the official JS routing client and demo at https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-js-client works for you? And if you look into the response headers you see that there is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*' but maybe something different we should solve

Comment: Official JS routing client works. but when I added code into my projects it would not work.

Comment: maybe you need to call 'jQuery.support.cors = true'?